# bwu_datagrid, lingering sorting indicators after reseting a dataView

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I'm using a "dataView" sans groups for my grid's dataprovider. 
After reseting the dataprovider, my last "sorted" column header remains on display along with the sorting arrow. Is there a way to force the columns "reset" all sorting indicators, etc?

I reset the data provider by:

```
...
if(grid != null){
   grid.invalidate();
   dataView.items = _newData;
   grid.setSortColumn('', false);
}
```

The only solution I've found so far is telling the grid to set a '' column as its sorting column. It just seems odd to have to do this when the datagrid knows that its dataprovider changed.

I'm on: 
SDK 1.15.0, 
Polymer1.0 1.0.0-rc.17

Comment: Have you tried to call `grid.render()` at the end?